# running tensorflow on a docker in arm1 mac

Tags: docker, tensorflow, ubuntu, dockerfile, arm

For some package reasons i need to run
`FROM --platform=linux/amd64 ubuntu:20.04`
as it seems arm1 mac now support docker on amd64, everything works fine. I can successfully install all my python packages.
However, when I run "import tensorflow" I receive the "Illegal instruction" error crashing python.
It seems that it is related to the architecture of the processor. How can I use tensorflow properly on a linux amd64 running on an arm1 processor? ( I don't care about the gpu)

I am running :

```
tensorflow-cpu==2.5.0
```

Comment: never heard of a mac made from an acorn arm1.  did you mean m1?